# Powermail broke on first click to submit

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions, parsley, powermail

I have an error with my powermail form. 
I copied one form from my site and made some little changes and now the new form doesn’t work right. 
When I click on submit the form isn’t send it only “destroys” the frontend and I have to fill the fields new to submit it (then it works).

I have this warning in the console: Parsley’s pubsub module is deprecated; use the ‘on’ and ‘off’ methods on parsley instances or window.Parsley

Do you have any idea? 
I’m new in the project and don’t created the first form.

Powermail: 3.22.1

TYPO3: 7.6.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if there are any redirects while form submitting. If forms are getting submitted and it seems that they are reloaded and empty, it often happens, that the form target is wrong. 
E.G. If absRefPrefix is set to http:// and there is an additional .htaccess redirection from http:// to https// or so the POST params get lost and powermail shows the form again.
You can check redirects in your browser console.

Comment: Thank you for the hints! We got a redirect from the normal URL to a URL with a language prefix (from test.com/kontakt to test.com/de/kontakt) and this was the problem. When we called the form with test.com/de/kontakt it worked...